# Como posso consultar quais são as queries mais pesadas no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

No banco de dados SQL Server, como é possível saber quais são as queries que mais consumiram recursos do banco de dados em sua execução?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use esta query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10
total_worker_time/execution_count AS Avg_CPU_Time
    ,execution_count
    ,total_elapsed_time/execution_count as AVG_Run_Time
    ,(SELECT
          SUBSTRING(text,statement_start_offset/2,(CASE
                                                       WHEN statement_end_offset = -1 THEN LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), text)) * 2 
                                                       ELSE statement_end_offset 
                                                   END -statement_start_offset)/2
                   ) FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
     ) AS query_text 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats 

--pick your criteria

ORDER BY Avg_CPU_Time DESC
--ORDER BY AVG_Run_Time DESC
--ORDER BY execution_count DESC
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499910/how-to-find-the-worst-performing-queries-in-sql-server-2008

No mesmo artigo existe um link para [este artigo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135978.aspx), que também dá várias dicas para encontrar problemas de performance.

**Mais um detalhe**: se quiser analisar o desempenho de um trecho T-SQL ou Procedure, execute o código no Management Studio com a opção `Include Actual Execution Plan`. Você verá um resultado em gráficos mostrando a porcentagem do peso das queries executadas e o custo de cada acesso a dados de cada parte da query.

Answer (score 3):

Existem ferramentas que podem te ajudar como o [NaviCat](http://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-sqlserver) que possui um recurso de monitoramento.
Ou o [Monyog](https://www.webyog.com/).
Se quiser fazer na mão existem esses comandos:

```sql
EXECUTE sp_who2
```

E com esse comando você consegue exatamente monitorar uma função/query específica:

```sql
DBCC INPUTBUFFER(spid)
```

Comment: Com exceção das ferramentas pagas, esses dois comandos só ajudam se a query pesada ainda estiver em execução ou se vocÊ sabe que ela foi a última query executada.